# rails generate scaffold fails ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm just getting my feet wet in rails development. Trying to learn from "Head First Rails", which is fairly out of date. But I'm updating the commands to more modern versions of rails.

Anyway, I'm trying to use the rails generate scaffold command and running into the following error:

```
     [root@web1:/var/www/tickets] #rails generate scaffold name:string seat_id_seq:string address:text price_paid:decimal email_address:string
      invoke  active_record
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/generators/base.rb:258:in `const_defined?': wrong constant name Name:string (NameError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/generators/base.rb:258:in `block in class_collisions'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/generators/base.rb:249:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/generators/base.rb:249:in `class_collisions'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/generators/named_base.rb:200:in `block in check_class_collision'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:115:in `invoke'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:277:in `block in _invoke_for_class_method'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/shell.rb:68:in `with_padding'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:266:in `_invoke_for_class_method'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:149:in `_invoke_from_option_orm'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/generators.rb:157:in `invoke'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/generate.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:135:in `generate_or_destroy'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `generate'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
        from /var/www/tickets/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I'm running ruby 1.9.3 via rvm and rails 4 via gem. The server is CentOS 7

I was just wondering if any of you might have run into a similar situation and know how I can get past this error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Usage:
  rails generate scaffold NAME [field[:type][:index] field[:type][:index]] [options]

Examples:
    `rails generate scaffold post`
    `rails generate scaffold post title body:text published:boolean`
```

You're not specifying name attribute, (i.e model)